# Windows Store Apps For each item in a XML file

Tags: windows-runtime, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

Can anyone point me in the rigth direction for a solution, to get data from a xml file. I normaly use XmlDocument in VB applications, and that have worked flawless all times.

Now Windows Store Apps not really supporting xmlDocument anymore, som working when DOM is imported but XmlNode is not availble. However maybe its just me but XDocument seems to me to be very very difficult and not very logic for looking up data in a simple XML file.

before i used some like this:

```
 xmlDevices = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Device")
 For Each xmlDevice As xmlElement In xmlDevices
  Dim strDeviceName As String = xmlDevice.Item("DeviceName").InnerText

  xmlModbuses = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Modbus")
  For Each xmlModbus As xmlElement In xmlModbuses
   Dim strModbusID As String = xmlModbus.Attributes("id").InnerText
  Next
 Next
```

The XML file i wants to seek data from looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Devices>
 <Device id="01">
  <DeviceName>VP18</DeviceName>
  <Modbusees>
   <Modbus id="01">1000</Modbus>
   <Modbus id="02">2000</Modbus>
   ...
  </Modbuses>
  <Alarms>
   <Alarm id="01">
    <AlarmText>Test</AlarmText>
    <AlarmType>Critical</AlarmType>
   </Alarm>
   <Alarm id="02">
    <AlarmText>Test</AlarmText>
    <AlarmType>Critical</AlarmType>
   </Alarm>
  </Alarms>
 <Device id="02">
  <DeviceName>VP19</DeviceName>
   <Modbusees>
    <Modbus id="01">1010</Modbus>
    <Modbus id="02">2020</Modbus>
    ...
  </Modbuses>
  <Alarms>
   <Alarm id="01">
    <AlarmText>Test</AlarmText>
    <AlarmType>Critical</AlarmType>
   </Alarm>
   <Alarm id="02">
    <AlarmText>Test</AlarmText>
    <AlarmType>Critical</AlarmType>
   </Alarm>
  </Alarms>
 </Device>
</Devices>
```

Best Regards
Thomas Nissen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with following.

```
        Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlStream.AsStreamForRead())

        Dim xmlDevices = xDoc.Root.Elements("Device")
        For Each xmlDevice In xmlDevices
            If xmlDevice.Attribute("id").Value = RoamingSettings.Containers("Device").Values("DeviceID") Then

                Dim xmlAlarms = xmlDevice.Descendants("Alarm")
                For Each xmlAlarm In xmlAlarms
                    If xmlAlarm.Attribute("id").Value = strAlarmID Then
                        strAlarmDisp = xmlAlarm.Element("AlarmDisp").Value
                        strAlarmType = xmlAlarm.Element("AlarmType").Value
                        strAlarmDesc = xmlAlarm.Element("AlarmDesc").Value
                        strAlarmHelp = xmlAlarm.Element("AlarmHelp").Value
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
```